# Giving Ownership/Rights properly on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, zend-server

I'm currently facing alot of issues with giving rights/ownership on Zend Server. I always do a

> chown user -R path/to/file

and

> giving 777 to fodlers and file then end up with lots of 777... with
>   some not needing that 777, If there is a user to zend server, i hope i
>   could just give it ownership to everything .... so i dont have to 777
>   so many stuff

**So far giving rights/ownership is fixing and CREATING issues with zend servers ...which is why i 'm here :(**

I'm also having issue debugging, when an error occurs i'm not sure how to check what caused it. I do read forums people doing a -debug behing their command. Sometimes i'm also not sure which file to give permission to. I realise my zend server is a User itself i believe...

any advice or guide would be greatly appreciated.

I have these as users

```
zend:x:106:112::/usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/:/bin/false
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

and many others. I think daemon and zend is related to zend server.

Comment: -r will remove read permissions, are you sure you dont mean -R for recursive? -r and -R are not the same thing

Comment: no. daemon is NOT related to zend.

Comment: @Anigel yea i meant recursive, thanks Marc B the new Issue i stated was actually due to unable to create a temporary file , i found a log. So it might be due to the change of permission that caused this issue. I Gave permission, not removed. not sure why that happened. Does chown give ownership to ONE person only?

Comment: PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0 example , i dont know which path it's trying to create the file in, how do i debug this?

Comment: you can use `sys_get_temp_dir()` to list the temp directory used. Reference [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note when giving permission for web server.

Permissions are simple. You just have to remember there is read write and execute permission in *nix. You won't need the execute permission in any of the script files but all folders must have execute permission. That leaves you with the read and write permissions. You will need read permission for all the files and folders. You will only need write permission only to the folders and files which need to be changed by the web server. Basically you will need read write and execute permissions for temp folder, and if you are using file upload then the folder where you store the files. You may need to have write permission only to files which needs to be changed by the web server (for simple sites these may not be there).

Comment: Just to check, if i do a chown , does it remove other users who are owners of the folder?

Comment: Root = Owner, Ubuntu(user) = group?

Comment: You have three permissions for each folder/file owner, group, all user. So if you change the owner the new owner gets the permissions that was applied to the previous owner. check this [Understanding Linux File Permissions](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)

Comment: if you execute `ls -l` the 3rd column is owner and 4th column is group and the first column is the permissions for each. To interpret the first column the first character is file/directory/link specification next 3 characters are permission for owner, then the next 3 is for group and the last 3 are for all others.

Comment: one doubt clear Thanks. How do i add my users to GROUP so i can prevent having a 777 instead. When Zend Server execute stuff, does it execute as Zend(user) or root? There is a user called zend. If it's executing using "Zend" i was thinking of adding this user to GROUP(how do i) then give all directory a 774

Comment: you can use `usermod -a -G toGroup user` . [Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group/)

Answer (score 2):

You should NEVER make a file executable (bit 0 set) that is not an executable shell script (CGI scripts such as PHP do NOT need execute permission), setting it to 777 is just plain lazy and dangerous from a security perspective.

I often run the following to correct permissions on a web folder:

```
chown username:groupname * -R
find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

This will give all directories:

- read permission by the owner, the group and anyone else
- write permission by the owner only
- execute permission which allows entering them and listing of their contents.

And it will give all files:

- read permission by the owner, the group and anyone else.
- write permission by the owner only.
- no execute permissions at all.

If you can add the Apache/HTTP server user to the user's group (`usermod -G apache -a username`), you can tighten this even further to 750 and 640 which will prevent other users from being able to read the web files (this can be bypassed via the webserver though depending on the server configuration).

Comment: How many users can own a folder, one right? But my zend server isnt able to write the log and etc. it seems to have permission issue. I'm not sure if zend is a user itself? if i give zend ownership , what about my ubuntu user and root user? They would lose the ownership? especially if it's a 755 only one person will be able to write? Am i right? ubuntu/Zend/root

Comment: A user can be in multiple groups, to see the groups a user is in run `id username`. Processes such as apache normally open the log files while they are running as 'root' and then they change their uid, this is why it can access them even if it is not running as the user.